# Output file is empty using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Starting from an input file (input.txt) i have to find some strings and write them in another file txt (output.txt) This is the input.txt

```
**********************************************************
* NAME           : CONTROLLER                                                          
* FUNCTION       : NOTHING IMPORTANT                                           
* BEGIN DATE     : 31/07/13                               
* TIME BEGIN     : 23.39.17.75                            
**********************************************************
* DATA INPUT READ  : 000000540                            
**********************************************************
```

And this is the code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objInputTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objInputTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\input.txt", ForReading, False)
Dim objOutputTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objOutputTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\output.txt", ForWriting, True)

Do Until objInputTS.AtEndOfStream
    Dim strLine
    strLine = objInputTS.ReadLine()
    If (Left(strLine, 13) = "BEGIN DATE:") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 20))
    If (Left(strLine, 13) = "TIME BEGIN:") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 20))
    If (Left(strLine, 18) = "DATA INPUT READ:") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 22))    
Loop

objOutputTS.Close()
objInputTS.Close()
```

But in the output file nothing appears. Any helps? i want this output for esxample

`20/05/2013 22/05/2013 21.00.00.00 0000000054`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
* BEGIN DATE     : 31/07/13
```

does not match the condition

```
If (Left(strLine, 13) = "BEGIN DATE:")
```

you have to ac**count** for the "* " prefix too.

**To spell it out:**

```
>> s1 = "* BEGIN DATE     : 31/07/13"
>> s2 = Left(s, 13)
>> WScript.Echo """" & s2 & """"
>>
"* BEGIN DATE "
>> c1 = "BEGIN DATE:"
>> c2 = "* BEGIN DATE "
>> WScript.Echo 1, CStr(c1 = s2)
>> WScript.Echo 2, CStr(c2 = s2)
>>
1 False
2 True
```

Comment: so what have i to do?

Comment: @David_D Take a look at the output of `WScript.Echo Left("* BEGIN DATE     : 31/07/13", 13)` and it should become obvious what you need to do.

Comment: sorry but it's first times i use vbs :( so the problem is the `*`?

Comment: really i don't know..nothing happen!

Comment: where have i to put this code? The problem is the count of `*` right?

Comment: something like a </br>